# Java SSL Client Auth: How to select alias in Keystore?

Tags: java, jsse

Trying to perform SSL client auth using JSSE, by initializing a SSLContext using a KeyManagerFactory, which is created using a Keystore.

This works fine if the Keystore has 1 certificate, but if it contains 2 different certificates issued by the same issuer, how can I tell SSLContext which certificate to use?

Answer (score 3):

Install your own `X509KeyManager` into the `SSLContext,` with your desired implementation of the [`chooseClientAlias()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509KeyManager.html#chooseClientAlias%28java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.security.Principal%5b%5d,%20java.net.Socket%29) method.